# linq query crossjoin groupby optimize

Tags: linq, optimization, linq-to-sql

i have the following database-model: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRtMD.png
the many to many relations for Kunde_Geraet/Kunde_Anwendung are in explicit Mapping-Table with additional Information.

i want to optimize the following LINQ-query:

```
var qkga = (from es in db.Eintrag_Systeme.Where(es => es.Eintrag_ID == id)
                   from kg in db.Kunde_Geraet.Where(kg => es.Geraet_ID == kg.Geraet_ID)
                   select new { Kunde = kg.Kunde, Geraet = es.Geraet, Anwendung = es.Anwendung })

                    .Union(
                  from es in db.Eintrag_Systeme.Where(es => es.Eintrag_ID == id)
                  from ka in db.Kunde_Anwendung.Where(ka => es.Anwendung_ID == ka.Anwendung_ID)
                  select new { Kunde = ka.Kunde, Geraet = es.Geraet, Anwendung = es.Anwendung })
                  .GroupBy(kga => kga.Kunde, kga => new {Geraet = kga.Geraet, Anwendung = kga.Anwendung});
```

it would be better, when the result is a IEnumerable(Kunde, IEnumerable(Geraet), IEnumerable(Anwendung)) without the null-Values for the union.

i try it as SQL command

```
select Count(es.Geraet_ID), null as Anwendung_ID
from Eintrag_Systeme es cross join Kunde_Geraet where es.Geraet_ID = Kunde_Geraet.Geraet_ID AND es.Eintrag_ID = @id
union
select null as Geraet_ID, Count(es.Anwendung_ID)
from Eintrag_Systeme es cross join Kunde_Anwendung where es.Anwendung_ID = Kunde_Anwendung.Anwendung_ID AND es.Eintrag_ID = @id
group by Kunde_ID
```

but don´t get the Count() of Anwendungen(Apps)/Geraete(Devices) to Lists grouped by Key Kunde(Client)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `join` but navigation properties:

```
from k in context.Kunden
select new
{
    Kunde = k,
    Geraete = k.Kunde_Geraete.Select(kg => kg.Geraet),
    Anwendungen = k.Kunde_Anwendungen.Select(ka => ka.Anwendung)
}
```

Now you have a basis from which you get counts, etc.